# C# mass File renamer

Tags: c#, file, io

i want to create C# mass file renamer, here is my UI
[image]

i have created `tes` folder, inside of `tes` there's a file which is `1.txt`.

i want to create my program to add prefix and suffix to the files, so `1.txt` will become
`prefix1suffix`

but then i got an error
[image]

it's said `file already exist` though there's only one file on `tes` folder, which is `1.txt` how do i make it work ? where's the error comes from ?

i have tried the following code

```
private void Rename(string prefix, string filepath, string suffix)
    {            
        //i don't use prefix suffix yet to make sure if my function works
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);
        FileInfo[] file = d.GetFiles();

        try
        {
            foreach (FileInfo f in file )
        {
            File.Move(f.FullName,"stackoverflow");
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            cmd.cetakGagal(e.ToString(), title);
        }
        cmd.cetakSukses("Rename Success", title);
    }
```

and it returns same error as the second picture above.

the following picture is `tes` folder, there's nothing in `tes` folder except `1.txt`

[image]

Comment: Step through the code yourself to find what file it is trying to move from/to when it errors. Hopefully the underlying problem and solution will then be obvious.

Comment: Well you aren't using the prefix and suffix parameters. How about you actually use them in the method and you will magically see your problem fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You are calling `File.Move()` with a full path for your `sourceFileName` and a relative path for your `destFileName`. The relative file path is relative to the current working directory and not to the source file path. I expect that a `stackoverflow` file exists in the current working directory, most likely created the first time you ran this code.

Answer (score 1):

your `File.Move` is changing them all to *StackOverflow* not using the prefix and suffix.  If you only have one file in the directory it shouldn't be an issue.  Are you sure there is only 1 file?

```
public static void Move(
    string sourceFileName,
    string destFileName
)
```

Looking at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19686884/2145211) might be the clue as you are specifying relative path for the destination file. To obtain the current working directory, see [GetCurrentDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getcurrentdirectory.aspx)

> The sourceFileName and destFileName arguments are permitted to specify
>   relative or absolute path information. Relative path information is
>   interpreted as relative to the current working directory.

You should change

```
File.Move(f.FullName,"stackoverflow");
```

to

```
string fileName = f.Name.Replace(f.Extenstion,string.Empty);
string newFileName = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}",prefix,fileName,suffix);
string newFileWithPath = Path.Combine(f.Directory,newFileName);
if (!File.Exists(newFileWithPath))
{
     File.Move(f.FullName,newFileWithPath);
}
```

Comment: yep i am sure that there's only 1 file, check my updated screenshot. can i make it to rename on the same folder without moving em ?

Comment: @Cignitor what did your debugging tell you if you put a breakpoint in the `foreach` loop.  Specifically, look at `files` and `file`

Answer (score 0):

The code above will give you that error since, after the first run through, "stackoverflow" exists as a file. Make sure that you check if the destination file exists (using `File.Exists`) before calling File.Move.

Answer (score 0):

Since your goal is renaming, I would suggest using a test folder filled with files rather than using a piecemeal approach.  See if something like this helps:

```
private void Rename(string prefix, string filepath, string suffix)
    {            
        //i don't use prefix suffix yet to make sure if my function works
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(filepath);
        FileInfo[] file = d.GetFiles();

        try
        {
            foreach (FileInfo f in file )
        {
            f.MoveTo(@filepath + @"\" + prefix + f.Name.Insert(f.Name.LastIndexOf('.'),suffix));
        }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            cmd.cetakGagal(e.ToString(), title);
        }
        cmd.cetakSukses("Rename Success", title);
    }
```

on a side note using a listview to display the filenames and the changes before they're committed will help prevent unwanted changes.